# How to login with Facebook in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, facebook-login

I followed this tutorial : https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle.

The versions I am using are Symfony 6.1.12 and PHP 8.1.0.

Currently, I log in with Google but not with Facebook. What did I miss ?

Thanks to `var_dump($user);` in my FacebookController.php, I can see my Facebook data appearing. But I don't connect with Facebook.

Because it works with Google, I am sharing also code from GoogleController.php and GoogleAuthenticator.php.

Thank you for your help.

My code in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml :

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        facebook:
            type: facebook
            client_id: '%env(OAUTH_FACEBOOK_ID)%'
            client_secret: '%env(OAUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET)%'
            redirect_route: connect_facebook_check
            redirect_params: {}
            graph_api_version: v2.12
```

In security.yaml :

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        oauth:
            id: knpu.oauth2.user_provider
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: home 
            entry_point: App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
                - App\Security\FacebookAuthenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/connect, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

I added variables in .env :

```
OAUTH_FACEBOOK_ID=fb_id
OAUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET=fb_secret
```

My FacebookController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FacebookController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/connect/facebook', name: 'connect_facebook')]
    public function connectAction(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        return $clientRegistry
            ->getClient('facebook')
            ->redirect([
                'public_profile', 'email'
            ], []);
    }

    #[Route('/connect/facebook/check', name: 'connect_facebook_check')]
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {

        /** @var \KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\Provider\FacebookClient $client */
        $client = $clientRegistry->getClient('facebook');

        try {
            /** @var \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\FacebookUser $user */
            $user = $client->fetchUser();
            
            var_dump($user); die;

        } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage()); die;
        }
    }
}
```

My GoogleController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class GoogleController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/connect/google', name: 'connect_google')]
    public function connectAction(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        //Redirect to google
        return $clientRegistry->getClient('google')->redirect([], []);
    }

    /**
     * After going to Google, you're redirected back here
     * because this is the "redirect_route" you configured
     * in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
     */
    #[Route('/connect/google/check', name: 'connect_google_check')]
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        // ** if you want to *authenticate* the user, then
        // leave this method blank and create a Guard authenticator
    }
}
```

My FacebookAuthenticator.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\FacebookUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class FacebookAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator implements AuthenticationEntrypointInterface
{
    private $clientRegistry;
    private $entityManager;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        // continue ONLY if the current ROUTE matches the check ROUTE
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_facebook_check';
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('facebook');
        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function() use ($accessToken, $client) {
                /** @var FacebookUser $facebookUser */
                $facebookUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);

                $email = $facebookUser->getEmail();

                // 1) have they logged in with Facebook before? Easy!
                $existingUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['facebookId' => $facebookUser->getId()]);

                if ($existingUser) {
                    return $existingUser;
                }

                // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
                $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

                // 3) Maybe you just want to "register" them by creating
                // a User object
                $user->setFacebookId($facebookUser->getId());
                $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                $this->entityManager->flush();

                return $user;
            })
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('home');

        return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
    
   /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/connect/', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }
}
```

And my GoogleAuthenticator.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GoogleUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Client\ClientRegistry;
use KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\OAuth2Authenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\SelfValidatingPassport;

class GoogleAuthenticator extends OAuth2Authenticator
{
    private ClientRegistry $clientRegistry;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->clientRegistry = $clientRegistry;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        // continue ONLY if the current ROUTE matches the check ROUTE
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'connect_google_check';
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $client = $this->clientRegistry->getClient('google');
        $accessToken = $this->fetchAccessToken($client);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge($accessToken->getToken(), function () use ($accessToken, $client) {
                /** @var GoogleUser $googleUser */
                $googleUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken);

                $email = $googleUser->getEmail();
                // have they logged in with Google before? Easy!
                $existingUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

                //User doesnt exist, we create it !
                if (!$existingUser) {
                    $existingUser = new User();
                    $existingUser->setEmail($email);
                    $existingUser->setGoogleId($googleUser->getId());
                    $existingUser->setHostedDomain($googleUser->getHostedDomain());
                    $this->entityManager->persist($existingUser);
                }
                $existingUser->setAvatar($googleUser->getAvatar());
                $this->entityManager->flush();

                return $existingUser;
            })
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {

        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->router->generate('home')
        );

        // or, on success, let the request continue to be handled by the controller
        //return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        $message = strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData());

        return new Response($message, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent.
     * This redirects to the 'login'.
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null): Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/connect/',
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help if you specify what version of Symfony and PHP.

Comment: Do you get some error currently?

Comment: No, it finally worked. I had to fix some parameters in Facebook website for developers.

Answer (score 2):

Your connectCheckAction is not blank, it should be if you use Symfony Authenticator and delete these lines in your security file :

````
         id: knpu.oauth2.user_provider
 enable_authenticator_manager: true```
````

Comment: Hello kasali. I deleted the two lines. The problem is still the same. I have this comment written in connectCheckAction : ```if you want to *authenticate* the user, then leave this method blank and create a Guard authenticator```. My question is because, there isn't many thing : Is this method already blank ? And should I create a Guard authenticator or what is written in FacebookAuthenticator is enough for the Authenticator ?

Comment: Your FacebookAuthenticator is enough. Could you share your errors?

Comment: I notice you added a scope named home in your connectAction method. This scope doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. Initially, it was ```public_profile```. I replaced it. I've changed it because I didn't what it was exactly.

Comment: I don't have any Symfony errors. But when I go to *connect_facebook* route, a Facebook link opens with the message : **Sorry, something went wrong... We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.**

Comment: See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822789/facebook-oauth2-sorry-something-went-wrong

Comment: Thank you for the post. I saw it yesterday. It looks like the problem happens in production mode for them. I'm still in dev mode.

Comment: Hello Emile, have you figured it out?

Comment: Yes, it has evolved. I no longer have the error. I have changed something in developers.facebook.com. However, I still can't connect with Facebook.

Comment: Whereas now I can log in with Google. So I updated my problem description.

Comment: Great! if you don't share the errors you are encountering it will be hard to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Facebook app authentication.
You should have appid,secret, domain and  https redirect url.
Try to host your site instead of localhost and make sure it is https.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/basic-settings/